# variable inside a string in Angular / typescript

Tags: string, angular, typescript

I have a service that I get an http from API

```
export class DataDisplayFromAPI {

result:any;

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

getPrices() {
    return this._http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,LTC,BCH,IOT,XRP&tsyms=USD")
    .map(result => this.result = result);
}
}
```

What I try to do is to replace the coins list `BTC,ETH,LTC,BCH,IOT,XRP` inside the string with a variable, as follow:

```
export class DataDisplayFromAPI {

result:any;
coinsList = 'BTC,ETH,LTC,BCH,IOT,XRP';

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

getPrices() {
    return this._http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=" + coinsList + "&tsyms=USD")
    .map(result => this.result = result);
}
}
```

But get error.

I tried also

```
return this._http.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=${coinsList}&tsyms=USD`)
```

But it also doesn't work

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: does it returns any error? and check out you network log and see the route that you are requesting to

Comment: **What error?** Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coinsList` is not defined in the method's scope. You need to refer to the component's scope with `this`

```
getPrices() {
    return this._http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms="
    + this.coinsList +
    "&tsyms=USD")
    .map(result => this.result = result);
}
```

or

```
getPrices() {
    return this._http.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=${this.coinsList}&tsyms=USD`)
        .map(result => this.result = result);
}
```